how to redirect to home.php who go to my domain
in control panel in public_html I have few files including home.php file.
my question is how can I set this page as assumption page.
my domain is example.com . I want see home.php who go to example.com/
how can I do this?
I search a lot in internet but no results.

Which hosting company are you using? And are you using a PHP framework (Wordpress, Laravel, etc.)? We need some more information - including error messages if there are any - as without more to go on it's not going to be possible to help

Maybe https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex is what you're looking for? Need more info if not.

Do you mean make home.php the index page?
